# want to know more about Dynamic Ip

Tags: c#, vb.net, ip

what do we mean by dynamic IP ?

and how we can implement a simple example on it using sockets in vb.net  ?

thanks all

Comment: http://whatismyipaddress.com/dynamic-static

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic IP"? Got any links to make your question a little clearer. At the moment it's a little lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dynamic IP address is assigned from a DHCP server (Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol).

When your network adapter connects to the network, it asks the DHCP server for a lease on an IP address. The DHCP server returns an IP address which has a limited life time. When the lease expires, the network adapter has to ask for a new lease.

The lifetime of a lease is usually something like two hours or 24 hours, whatever is appropriate for the network. A short lifetime for the lease doesn't mean that you change IP address often, because most of the time you will get a lease for the same IP address that you had before.

For a static IP address the DHCP server isn't involved, you simply enter the IP adress in the network settings.

You can't implement dynamic IP addresses using sockets, because you need to have an IP address already to establish a socket connection.

Answer (score 1):

Read a book about the IP prtocol and the WIndows doucmentation.

Dynamic IP refers to an IP address that is dynamically assigned to a computer when the computer connects to the physical network ,by means of a DHCP server which dynamically configures the host (with a dynamic IP). The opposite is a STATIC IP which is hard-coded into the computer configuration (i.e. you set it statically).

More is in the documentation. This is a low level beginner question - answering it without a lot of context is hard. Books and Documentation provide the context.